# How to extract certain value from a collection of ember data?

Tags: ember.js

Code below is my current solution,

```
  tagsValue: Ember.computed('tags.@each', {
    get() {
      const out = [];
      this.get('tags').forEach((tag) => {
        out.push(tag.get('value'));
      });
      return out;
    }
  }),
```

Is there a better way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below,

```
  tagsValue: Ember.computed('tags.@each', {
    get() {
      return this.get('tags').mapBy('value');
    }
  }),
```